# Is it ok to change CPU rate limit of SID mid process?

Tags: windows-7, windows, cpu, cpu-usage, regedit

One process in particular is using a lot of CPU (100% and raising temps to 95C) which needs to run for long period of time(~3 hrs). Using this [guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/ff384148(v=ws.10)) helped limit the usable bandwidth of CPU to 50%. But unfortunately it slowed that process considerably(~9hrs), is it ok if I raised the CPU rate limit to higher number mid process.

Process does not allow changing affinity or priority!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A temperature of 95°C is abnormally high and indicates a cooling problem in your PC, not an "overuse" of the CPU by software.  There are usually several things you can do to improve cooling - switch the machine off before attempting any of the following:

- [Remove dust that may be clogging vents, fans and heatsinks.](https://www.pcworld.com/article/2037100/youre-a-dirty-dirty-dusty-pc.html)  The CPU heatsink is especially important.  Ensure that any fans fitted rotate freely (don't spin them by hand, just move them gently) and are correctly plugged in.
- Ensure that air can flow freely through all vents on the outside of the machine.  Some under-desk mounting brackets are notoriously bad for this.
- If the above is insufficient to cure the problem, remove the heatsink, [clean both surfaces using rubbing alcohol](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/How+to+Apply+Thermal+Paste/744) (tape or lens cleaning fluid), and apply a small quantity of [fresh thermal paste](https://pcpartpicker.com/product/6RrG3C/arctic-silver-thermal-paste-as535g) before reassembling.  The linked tube is sufficient for at least a dozen applications.  While you're doing this, ensure that any plastic protective layer has been removed from under the heatsink (don't laugh, it sometimes happens even with "professional" builds).
- If even this is insufficient, you may need to install [a better heatsink](https://pcpartpicker.com/product/hmtCmG/cooler-master-cpu-cooler-rr212e20pkr2).  The stock Intel heatsink is very weak.  The new series of AMD heatsinks (recognisable by an AMD logo on top of the shroud) should be fine for the CPU they were supplied with, as long as the fan works.

The above points apply to a normal desktop computer, which is designed to be user-serviceable.  In laptops and all-in-one machines, the same principles theoretically apply, but [much more care is required when disassembling](https://www.tomsguide.com/us/Laptop-Notebook-Overheating,review-1596.html) to renew thermal paste, and fitting an upgraded heatsink is usually impossible.